# Facebook login logout implementation

Tags: facebook, events, authentication

Beeing new with the facebook thing. How do you get the user information after the log in?
Here is the code:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
</body>
```

I red that I have to subscribe to the auth.login event and then use the FB.api... great but how do you do that?

I tried the following:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
  FB.auth.login{
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          alert(response.name);
        });
      }
    };

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help. And sorry if I look stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you initialize the facebook sdk (using *FB.init*) you can start using it for requests, events, etc.

The [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) talks about 5 *Auth Methods*. Which one you need depends on what you want to do and if the user already authorized your application and the permissions you are about to use.

If the user is not logged in to your application you need to use [login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // logged in
    }
    else {
        // not logged in
    }   
});
```

If he is already logged in, or you don't know what his status use [getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app
        FB.api("/me", function(apiresponse) {
            console.log("api result: ", apiresponse);
        });
    }
    else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app
    }
    else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
});
```

To make api requests use the [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) method as in the example I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

For the very beginners: I had to put the piece of code Nizan gave me and add it after the FB.init call as following:

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'APP_ID',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === "connected") {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app
    alert("You are logged in");
}
else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app
}
else {
    alert("You are not logged");
}
});
};
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
 </script>
 <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
</body>
</html>
```